# The fullcalendar event does not end on the specified end date

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I use full-calendar to display the availability of a doctor. I created an event with a start date and an end date but end date is not taken into account. The event takes the whole calendar.
Below is the code that generates the event:

```
events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                self.events = [];
                self.service
                    .getListdoctor(self.input)
                    .subscribe((rdoctor) => {
                        rschUnit.forEach((item) => {
                            let d = new Date();
                            let date = self.datePipe.transform(d, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                            let event = {
                                id: item.ebRschUnitScheduleNum,
                                resourceId: item.hospitalNum,
                                start: date + "T" + "08:00:00", 
                                end: date + "T" + "09:00:00", 
                                title: Busy,
                                eventColor: "#00cc66",
                            };
                            self.events.push(event);
                        });

                        successCallback(self.events);
                    });             }
```

and here is the result in picture
[image]

I expect the end date to be "09:00:00"

Comment: So it should start at 8am and end at 9am on the _same_ day, is that correct? Where is it ending now, does it end at the next day, or something else? From the code you've shown there should be no problem, it should end at the right time, it's using `date` in both cases.

Comment: @ADyson The event should normally takes the range houre that I specified, ie 8h-9h but it takes all day

Comment: I doubt that - if anything I suspect it probably ends at 9am on on a later day - try navigating forward a few days and see where it ends. Also please try logging `event` to your console and seeing what data is _actually_ in there. Then we can have a better idea what's really going on.

Comment: @ADyson, here is an exemple of the output in the debugger ``end: "2020-05-28T09:00:00"
eventColor: "#00cc66"
id: 1
resourceId: 6
start: "2020-05-28T08:00:00"
title: "doc-A07031 - STV"`` I get the same issue it ignores the calendar. The events begin on 2020-05-28T08:00:00 and end at 2020-05-29 at 11 pm

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using the data provided. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRpbaMa . It's impossible for the calendar to behave in the way you've described when using that event data. (P.S. as a separate point, `eventColor` isn't a [recognised property of an event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) so in the demo I changed it to `color` which is what I assume you wanted. Perhaps you confused it with the global [eventColor](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventColor) option which can be set at the calendar level).

Comment: @ADyson exactly I wanted to get the color property of the event. On the demo that you reproduced, the event respects the time range well (with javascript) but I don't understand why on angular it doesn't work

Comment: It's not clear either. TBH Angular shouldn't directly affect anything, fullCalendar doesn't use it internally and, other than some angular functions to actually fetch the original data, you're not doing anything angular-specific when you give the data to fullCalendar. The only other issue I can think of is perhaps something somehow CSS-related - from the screenshot it seems you've customised the CSS a bit, so maybe something is accidentally overflowing or something. Try and test using fullCalendar's default CSS, just to see if we can rule that out as an issue.

Comment: if you need any more help than that, maybe try and make a runnable demo of your code on codesandbox or similar, so we can see the problem in action. It's always far easier to diagnose a problem if you can actually interact with it.

Comment: @ADyson, you're right this is a css problem. The timeline css was missing I imported ``@import '~@fullcalendar/timeline/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/timeline/main.min.css'; ``in ``style.main.scss``. Everything works fine. Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Glad you found it. If that's all it was, you can probably delete the question, it's unlikely to be much use to future readers.